# PHP sqlsrv query with diacritic signs: fine in Managment Studio, no results in app

Tags: php, sql-server, diacritics, ssms, sqlsrv

I do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.value = 'ó'`

In MS SQL Managment Studio it gives results.
In PHP it gives no results. Why?

My connection string:

```
$_dbHandler = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$_dbConfig['server']};Database={$_dbConfig['dbName']};", $_dbConfig['username'], $_dbConfig['password']);
$_dbHandler->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

Query building goes standard `prepare`, `bindValue`, `setFetchMode`, `execute`.

All my strings are ASCII, files encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Is the web page you display it on utf-8?  Header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Andomar yeah; that made me thinking how I handle inputs and found line that breaks sutff: `htmlentities($searchPhrase, ENT_NOQUOTES)`; the question now is why it happens, but that's another story. Thnx